# Kotlin/Andriod/Jetpack compose: How to fix java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt

Tags: kotlin

W/MobStoreFlagStore: Unable to update local snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.elbehiry.delish, may result in stale flags.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.elbehiry.delish, sha256=[6ae4dbe1a874ffc2ab026a6586da2f2885f7484e36ac11f92f5425319b9f9318], atk=false, ver=230413040.true (go/gsrlt)

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.